# How to pull information from an HTML tag into a php variable?

Tags: php

I'm working with a form that takes some user inputs and then calculates the price. When the 'submit' button is pressed, the form information will be send via email to the webmaster.

To assemble this email, I can load form choices into php variables, i.e.:
`<input name="email">` is accessible via `$email = $_POST["email"]`.

I want to do the same for non-input/non-select elements. My form contains multiple instances of `<select>` elements that have `.on('change')` jQuery handlers attached to them to listen for changes and manipulate a `<span>` that displays the price based on what's chosen.

For the email I'm sending, I want to get both the selected option (which I can do with `$_POST`) and the dynamically updated corresponding price.

But given that price is just in a `<span>`-tag, how would I access it (what I'm looking for is a php equivalent of jQuery's `$('#price').html()`)?

Comment: Data from `span` is not passed to server. You can put data into `hidden` fields and process on server side.

Comment: I would recommend just getting the selected options, and looking up the prices again on the server side. It's fine to display them to your users, but accepting prices generated on the client side seems pretty risky as those types of things can easily be manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a `.on('change')` event handler to set the span content, you can add there a code to set the `<input type="hidden" name="the_same_price_as_in_span">` value as well.

Although you shouldn't pass values generated on client side, because you can never be sure if the values haven't been changed - somebody could set the price to 0. You should calculate the price like you do in `.on('change')` event but on the server side. That way you will be sure that you have the right price.